# Android code to check condition if variable exits or not from rest api

Tags: android, rest, if-statement, json

Hi my question is regarding Android programming. I have a varible called `company_name` which i must fetch from Rest api and print on my Android device.

But my question is i must check for a condition if the `company_name`(variable) exists or not, if not then it must skip it and print others.

My code:

```
try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    final JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");


                    final List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject inter = new JSONObject(jsonArray.get(i).toString());
                        ApplyJobItem jobItem = new ApplyJobItem();
                        jobItem.setCompanyName(inter.getString("company_name"));
                        jobItem.setIndustry(inter.getString("industry_selected"));
                        jobItem.setJobPost(inter.getString("title"));
                        jobItem.setJobType(inter.getString("type"));
                        jobItem.setJobId(inter.getString("_id"));
                        //jobItem.setJobCity(inter.getString("location"));
                        //jobItem.setJobSalary(inter.getJSONArray("salary_range").getString(0) + " to " + inter.getJSONArray("salary_range").getString(1));
                        jobItem.setdescription(inter.getString("description"));
                        names.add(inter.getString("company_name"));
                        names.add(inter.getString("industry_selected"));
                        names.add(inter.getString("title"));
                        // names.add(inter.getString("description"));
                        applyJobItems.add(jobItem);
                        android.util.Log.e("Company name", inter.getString("company_name"));
                    }

                        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(apply.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, names);
                        final boolean isCareer = jsonObject.getBoolean("careerUpdated");
                        android.util.Log.e("Entered ", "1");
                        applyJobAdapter = new ApplyJobAdapter(apply.this, applyJobItems, isCareer);
                        android.util.Log.e("Entered ", "2");
                        ListView mylistview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
                        android.util.Log.e("Entered ", "3");
                        mylistview.setAdapter(applyJobAdapter);
                        android.util.Log.e("Entered ", "4");


                        mylistview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), applypage.class);
                                intent.putExtra("careerUpdate", isCareer);
                                intent.putExtra("position", position);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: `.has `property could help I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `inter.has("company_name")` to check if `company_name` key exist or not in your `JSONObject`.

```
  //...
 jobItem.setdescription(inter.getString("description"));

 if(inter.has("company_name")){
    names.add(inter.getString("company_name"));
    names.add(inter.getString("industry_selected"));
    names.add(inter.getString("title"));
    applyJobItems.add(jobItem);
    android.util.Log.e("Company name", inter.getString("company_name"));
 } else {
    android.util.Log.e("Company name", "Not exist");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check in your JsonObject if 'company_name' key exists or not -

```
if(inter.has("company_name"))
    //Continue you processing
else
    //Stop reading the data
```